# How long will store kit keep unfinished transactions?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, storekit

I'm working on this app with in app purchase enabled.
The happy path is all covered, everything is fine, I'm trying to work out the non happy path.

To put it simply, the purchase is bound to a server side component.
On purchase, when the transaction is in the "Purchased" state, I'm supposed to go out to the server, which will enable the user's account.
When the request comes back, I then clean up some stuff and eventually call -finishTransaction: on the SKPaymentQueue.

The non happy path is pretty much when the server call fails for whatever reason. Network not available, network timeout, the user closed the app right after purchasing it and just before I could make the server call, you name it.

My tests in the 5.1 simulator with a sandbox account show me that an unfinished Purchased transaction will come back in the queue on next start up, and my delegate will be properly called with it.
But, after a little while, say 5 minutes for instance, boom, gone is the transaction.
Considering the whole stability of sandbox accounts, I'm willing to call that on the simulator's implementation, but it's hard to tell.

What's the appropriate way of dealing with this problem?

Bonus question: when does apple actually charge somebody? Sounds like it should be AFTER the app called -finishTransaction:, but I couldn't find any evidence of this anywhere.

Thanks,
/kra

UPDATE:
testing on physical device, almost an hour and the transaction is still there. Looks like the transactions disappearing is a simulator thing.

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented In-App purchases I gave up on testing it in the simulator. The behavior is just too different. Test it on the device and see whether it works there.

I'm also interested in your question about the charging, since I'm not entirely sure about it either (my app isn't released yet ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's pretty much the conclusion I'm getting to, sandbox is completely unreliable, and you have to take a leap of faith before going to prod. Some earlier tests on device tipped me that they would always come back (and a bit of common sense indicates that too). Testing on devices isn't exactly reliable either, I've had my share of uninstall, reboot, reinstall thanks to store kit freaking out with the dreaded "Can't reach the appstore" error.

Comment: I have to say that I didn't really get into too much trouble when testing on the device. I followed this guide very closely: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/. The only thing that bugs me sometimes, is that it returns invalid product id's after doing some recompiles - when that happens I just have to delete and build/run again though. The whole code-sign relation to product id's is also still magic for me - for example I don't get why it works when doing an adhoc-testrollout with the debug signing.

Comment: Yeah, that part is pretty much ok, my problem was more with switching between sandbox accounts. At some point, StoreKit just gives up, constantly returns a phony error no matter what you do, and you pretty much have to uninstall/reboot the phone/reinstall. I don't recall any issue with the code signing, you just have to be careful to use a specific provisioning profile, not a wildcard one. As long as the items are available, it should work regardless of the cert.

Comment: Yeah see, here is the thing: For the ad-hoc test provisioning on the other hand I do need the wildcard one. For some reason it seems that two provisioning profiles are active since both aspects work: I can give testers the app and they can test the In-App store. It makes sense but I'm confused why it works.